# make paging table in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pagination

I make a search function, and I want use paging in my result table I already try but not working properly. I want show just 10 row but when I try that not working.

I read in https://codeigniter.com/ how to Pagination, but I still don't understand how to use this into my code:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['total_rows'] = ;
```

this is my code:

controller:

```
function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct($securePage=false);
         $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->model('tracking_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('tracking_view');
                $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

function searchTiket(){
        // Retrieve the posted search term.
        $noTicket = $this->input->post('trackTicket');
        $monthTicket = $this->input->post('trackMonth');
        $yearTicket = $this->input->post('trackYear');
        // Use a model to retrieve the results.

        //pengaturan pagination
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'';
        $config['total_rows'] = '200';
        $config['per_page'] = '5';

//inisialisasi config
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

//buat pagination
        $data['page'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

// Use a model to retrieve the results.
        $data["result"]= $this->tracking_model->searchTiket($config['per_page'],$noTicket,$monthTicket,$yearTicket);

        // Pass the results to the view.
        $this->load->view('tracking/ticket_list_view',$data);
    }
```

view:

```
<div>
<center>

<?php if(empty($result)){
    echo '<h2>Data not found!</h2>';
}else{
?>

    <table border='1' Width='1000'>  
        <tr bgcolor= #ff9900>
        <th style="color: white"> No. Tiket </th>
        <th style="color: white"> Kategori </th>
        <th style="color: white"> Status </th>
        <th style="color: white"> Tanggal dibuat </th>
        <th style="color: white"> Tanggal masuk ke IT </th>
        <th style="color: white"> Estimasi Selesai </th>
        <th style="color: white"> Tindakan </th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        foreach($result as $row){?>
<?php 
if ($row->Status =="OPEN") {
    $image = '<img alt="Brand" src="assets/img/remind.png" width="25" height="25" /> Reminder';
} elseif ($row->Status =="Masih menunggu approval Atasan" || $row->Status =="Masih menunggu approval PIC HO") {
    $image = '<img alt="Brand" src="assets/img/fast_forward.png" width="25" height="25" /> Percepat';
} elseif($row->Status =="Sudah Selesai"){
    $image = '<img alt="Brand" src="assets/img/Reopen.png" width="25" height="25" /> Reopen';
} else {
    $image ="";
}

?>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <!-- <td bgcolor= #fff><?php echo $row->ticket_id; ?></td> -->
    <td><a id="btn_preview"  action="<?php echo base_url() ?>tracking/showDetail?ticket_id=<?php echo $row->ticket_id; ?>"><?php echo $row->ticket_id; ?></a></td>
            <td bgcolor= #fff><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
            <td bgcolor= #fff><?php echo $row->Status; ?></td>
            <td bgcolor= #fff><?php echo $row->created_time; ?></td>
            <td bgcolor= #fff><?php echo $row->start_IT; ?></td>
            <td bgcolor= #fff><?php echo $row->estimasi_selesai; ?></td>
            <td bgcolor= #fff><?php echo $image; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
        <?php }?>
                </table>
                <div class="halaman">Halaman : <?php echo $page;?></div>
                </center>
                </div>

                <?php
            } 
?>
```

Model:

```
function searchSpv()
{

$findTicket=$this->db->query("my query");

return $findTicket->result();
}
```

Comment: What is your current output? How many rows showing?

Comment: I want to show only 10 rows for each pages but all of rows show in first page.

Comment: Can you post your model code?

Comment: I already add my model code @AdhanTimothyYounes

Comment: what is your query?

Comment: I just use select from my table,
I just want pagging my query result
 @AdhanTimothyYounes

Comment: Can you go to this link: https://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Comment: I still dont understand how to use 
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['total_rows'] = ;
In my code

Answer (score 0):

For `$config['base_url']` you have to add the url that loads the view page having pagination.

For example, if the `www.example.com/index.php/controller_name/function_name` is the url for the pagination, where you defined the pagination and loads the view page having pagination in the function `function_name()` in the controller `Controller_name`, then,

**`$config['base_url']  =  'www.example.com/index.php/controller_name/function_name';`**

or

**`$config['base_url']  =  site_url().'/controller_name/function_name';`**

Then, next is `$config['total_rows']`. This the total number of rows or records including all the pages.

Suppose there are 1000 rows of data on which we have to implement pagination. What ever the number of pages, regardless of the current active page, this 1000 rows are not going to change. You can show 10 records or 50 records or 100 records or other you wish to show in per page, but this total number of records remains unchanged.

That means,

**`$config['total_rows']=1000;`**

In most of the case, this would be a dynamic data. So if we run a query to fetch the records from database; for getting the `$config['total_rows']`, we have to count the total number of records retrieved by that query.

If pagination is for static records of data, then we can simply add the total number of rows statically(manually) since we have a pre idea about the total number of records.